# How to increase client_max_body_size for a Spring Boot application on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created my Spring Boot application .jar file using Gradle's `build/bootJar` and then deployed it to Elastic Beanstalk. But when I do a POST request with large data I get the following error message:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>nginx/1.14.1</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried adding `client_max_body_size 50M;` to a `myconf.conf` file which is located `{project_root}/.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf` and rebuild and redeploy the .jar file but this does not work.

I've also tried moving that same `.ebextensions` folder `{proejct_root}/src`, that does not work either.

Anything else I can try? I wonder if creating the .jar using `bootJar` is the correct way.

Comment: Did you find any way to do that? I am facing the same situation :(

Comment: @narzero Same here. Did you find any solution? :|